# Algorithm to place N employees in M positions with roles

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve a mathematical problem using an algorithm, but I'm not able to develop the right one.

The problem is:

> I have a list of employees (Jack, John, Al, ...).
>
> I have a list of roles (R1, R2, R3, ...).
>
> I have a list of working positions (W1, W2, W3, ...).

Every employee has a set of roles, like Jack has R1 and R2, Al has R2 and R3, John has only R1.

Every working position has a set of roles that can support, like to work in position W1 you need R1 or R2, in position W2 you need R3, in position W3 you need R1 or R3.

So I need to find the best configuration of employees - working positions, to be sure that every working position has an employee with the right roles to work there.

I developed a couple of solutions in `PHP` that work pretty good but now and then, depending on the order of placing, don't choose the best configuration and leave a working position unoccupied.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can one employee be at several positions?

Comment: Nope. One position for one employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would proceed, for a polynomial algorithm.

First of all, let's simplify the input. We can get rid of roles if we directly associate employees to working positions they can occupy. To do this, you can for instance construct a table role -> employees with this role, and then a table position -> appropriate employees (putting the employees from the corresponding roles cells from the other table).

This leaves you with a position <-> employees relation.

Then, you can see it as a maximum matching problem. If you see each employee and each position as a node, you want to match the most nodes possible (i.e. 2*|positions| in the best case).

This being a bipartite graph (there is a link between an employee and a position if this employee can occupy this position, no links between employees or between positions), you can solve it with a polynomial algorithm, for instance using flows (put a 1 capacity on each link, a sink linked with the employees and a source with the positions, for instance). Please look here for a detailled solution http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/ (AFAIK, a BFS-based solution will work great as well).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting reply. I hoped to avoid the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm and maybe find a lightweight shortcut. I'll try with maximum bipartite matching. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are OK with losing efficiency and prefer this algorithm, you can use the Hungarian algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

I guess you can set the cost to 1 when there is a link and infinity otherwise.

Comment: I'll try the Hungarian algorithm, I need to find if every position can be occupied by one employee, to check if the employees list for that day is valid. Thanks!